# how to get rid of section names in fancyhdr headline

Tags: fancyhdr

i just want to have the main chapter name in the headline, not the section name (on the left), as you can see in the picture[image]

my code looks like this :

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}


\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark{}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: You should provide a test file but probably `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}` will stop sections setting a mark.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that a test file is needed, your comment helped me to solve my problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The details depend on the documentclass and other parts not shown, but probably

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
```

will stop sections setting a mark.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the standard headers before defining what you want in yours.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just to make smaller pictures
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}% clear all headers
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}% define what we want

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Test chapter}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Test section}

\lipsum[2-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]